# Какой метод следует использовать для проверки форм такого типа?

Tags: java, selenium, test-automation

Есть форма с полями авторизации пользователя: [image: скриншоте]

Я хотел бы ее протестировать с помощью Selenium. В сети наткнулся на такой пример(ниже фрагмент кода):

```
@Test
    public void inValid_UserCredential()
    {
        System.out.println("Starting test " + new Object(){}.getClass().getEnclosingMethod().getName());
        driver.get("http://192.168.35.10/");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='account']/a")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.id("E-Mail")).sendKeys("testuser");
        driver.findElement(By.id("Passwort")).sendKeys("Test@123");
        driver.findElement(By.id("login")).click();
        try{
            element = driver.findElement (By.xpath(".//*[@id='account_logout']/a"));
        }catch (Exception e){
        }
        Assert.assertNotNull(element);
        System.out.println("Ending test " + new Object(){}.getClass().getEnclosingMethod().getName());
    }
```

Как я понимаю, этот фрагмент вводит неправильные данные в поля и кликает.Однако вопрос в следующем.Тест не работает как надо для полей того типа,что я показал на скришоте и я думаю, что вот тут `By.id("E-Mail")` ошибка. Надо,что бы он сомтрел не по id, а по какому-то другому параметру(чтобы находил эти поля и вводил в них то,что показано в скобках). Верно ли я понимаю это и если да, что мне следует поменять,чтобы исправить эту ошибку?

Comment: Понимание правильное. Открывайте DOM и смотрите на свой компонент

Comment: я в этой теме не очень опытный человек, а что такое DOM?

Comment: почитайте вот эту тему http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#locating-ui-elements-webelements

Comment: большое спасибо,то,что надо. и еще вопрос возник. что значит вот эта строчка с регуляркой ' driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='account']/a")).click(); '

Comment: Это не совсем регулярка, это так описывается xpath. Про него можно почитать тут http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_intro.asp